# How to make text fill up entire page on mobile browser?

Tags: html, css

I have a very simple HTML page that shows bitcoin prices, on mobile it looks terrible because the text is really small and there is a lot of empty space on the right.  How can I make this so it fills up the width of the page?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML in 10 Simple Steps or Less</title>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60" />
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://widgets.coingecko.com/coingecko-coin-list-widget.js"></script>
<coingecko-coin-list-widget coin-ids="ethereum,bitcoin,aave,convex-finance,dopex,dydx" currency="usd" locale="en" width="300""></coingecko-coin-list-widget>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Screenshot]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRo9L.jpg

Comment: Please share your css and the rendered html for this coin list widget.

Comment: I am not a web developer so I just have the code I posted above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following header tags will prevent the device from scaling automatically and allow you to take control.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">
```

Then, assuming its an iframe, apply this CSS:

```
iframe{width:100%}
```

Comment: that did it!  I did not have to use the iframe line but putting the two meta commands inside the head fixed it!  Thank you so much!